# Need to get cx_freeze (or Pyinstaller) to pick up Taurus package.

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, pyqt, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I can't seem to get cx_freeze to pick up Taurus. Taurus is similar to PyQt and PySide. I designed me GUI with Taurus Designer (similar to QT Designer). Interestingly enough cx_freeze picks up PySide which isn't even used. I think it may be confusing Taurus with PySide somehow. I've tried excluding PySide which it does, however it still wont pick up Taurus. Taurus is located in site-packages. I also tried specifically including Taurus in packages to no avail. I'm using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 15.04- 64. Does anyone have a solution?

Here's my setup script as it now stands:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os","taurus","taurus.external.qt"],   "excludes": ["tkinter, PySide"], "includes": ["ui_geospect"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "gs_ard",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("gs_ard.py", base=base)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `taurus` in the `includes` and not in `packages`:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"includes": ["taurus", "taurus.external.qt", "ui_geospect"], "excludes": ["tkinter, PySide"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "gs_ard",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("gs_ard.py", base=base)])
```

The `packages` option is for your local packages. Also you do not need to specify python built-in modules (`os`) since they are included by default together with the python interpreter (it won't hurt leaving them in though).

Comment: Still not picking up Taurus, but thanks for the info. Taurus is located in site-packages btw.